# Getting HTTP Error remotely instead of 'Connection was reset message'

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, file-upload

On an ASP.NET Web Application I have an upload file functionality. I'm restricting the file size up to 10 MB by configuring the inside web.config the **maxAllowedContentLength** attribute. (I'm using IIs 7.0 BTW).

It get the desired HTTP Error when I access the application from the local machine:

HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.

When I access the application from another machine I get

The connection was reset
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

How can I get a more descriptive error when my application is accessed remotely?

Thanks,

Maria.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this myself.  I got the "connection to server reset error" when trying to upload a 40 MB file after setting the maxRequestLength to 50384.  I did not get the 404.13 error that is commonly referenced for the issue.

In addition to the httpRuntime web.config setting IIS 7 has a default request filtering limit of 30 MB that can be overridden.  Below is my example for how to edit your web.config to allow uploading 50 MB files on IIS 7:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" maxRequestLength="50384" executionTimeout="3600" requestLengthDiskThreshold="1200"/>
...
```

---

```
    <system.webServer>
     <security>
       <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="60000000"></requestLimits>
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was having a the same problem. I put in both of these attributes and it worked for me. If someone has an explanation that would be awesome.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(VS.71).aspx

Regards,
Kieran